# Django Serializer Dataset Context

Tags: python, django, serialization

Is there a way to access the entire dataset that will be processed by the serializer before it does so.

The Reason for this is because there is a bulk process I would like to do before I serialize the data. This is so that I can improve the performance of the serializing process to improve the delivery speed to the client(this is not required when creating only on retrieving)

```py
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def before_process(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # TODO: Some bulk work here with the self.full_unprocessed_dataset
        self.bulk_results = from_the_above_result

    def some_function_field(self):
        return self.bulk_results['some_key']
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use validate method.

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def validate(self,attrs):
    # your data inside attrs you can access like that
        your_field_value = attrs['your_field']
```

Comment: Is this not only triggered when creating ?

Comment: Yes, validate method triggered only creating.Do you want access data for listing?

Comment: Yes, that is what I require for what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You can use `update` method on `Serializer`?

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    content = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    created = serializers.DateTimeField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Comment(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
        instance.content = validated_data.get('content', instance.content)
        instance.created = validated_data.get('created', instance.created)
        return instance
```